# Error when checking target: expected dense_18 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10,)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

```
  Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 10)#
    random_seed = 2
    X_train,X_val,Y_train,Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size = 0.1, random_state=random_seed)
    Y_train.shape
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 86, epochs = 3,validation_data = (X_val, Y_val), verbose =2)
```

I have to classify the MNIST data into 10 classes. I am converting the Y_train into one hot encoded array. I have gone through a number of answers but none have helped. Kindly guide me in this regard as I am a novice in ML and neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no need to use `model.add(Flatten())` in your first layer. Instead of doing so, you can use a dense layer with a specific input size like: `model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=your_input_shape, activation="relu")`.

To ensure this issue happens because of the layers, you can check whether `to_categorical()` function works alone with jupyter notebook.

## Updated Answer

Before the model, you should reshape your model. In that case 28*28 to 784.

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((-1, 784))
test_images = test_images.reshape((-1, 784))
```

I also suggest to normalize the data that could be done by simply dividing the images to 255

After that step you should create your model.

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
Dense(64, activation='relu'),
Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
])
```

Have you noticed `input_shape=(784,)` That is the shape of your flattened input.

Last step, compiling and fitting.

```
model.compile(
optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(
train_images,
train_labels,
epochs=10,
batch_size=16,
)
```

What you do is you have just flattened the input layer without feeding the network with an input. That's why you experience an issue. The point is you should manually reshape your inputs and feed forward to the `Dense()` layers with parameter `input_shape`

Comment: I tried adding a model.Dense with input shape as(10,) however I am getting 'Error when checking input: expected dense_42_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (34020, 28, 28, 1) '

Comment: @shreyanshupadhyay, I will update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation